# convert Kitti labels to Yolo

Tags: python, machine-learning, label, object-detection, yolo

Trying to convert Kitti label format to Yolo. But after converting the bbox is misplaced.
this is kitti bounding box

[image: this is Kitti bounding box]

This is conversion code:

```
def convertToYoloBBox(bbox, size):
# Yolo uses bounding bbox coordinates and size relative to the image size.
# This is taken from https://pjreddie.com/media/files/voc_label.py .
dw = 1. / size[0]
dh = 1. / size[1]
x = (bbox[0] + bbox[1]) / 2.0
y = (bbox[2] + bbox[3]) / 2.0
w = bbox[1] - bbox[0]
h = bbox[3] - bbox[2]
x = x * dw
w = w * dw
y = y * dh
h = h * dh
return (x, y, w, h)


convert =convertToYoloBBox([kitti_bbox[0],kitti_bbox[1],kitti_bbox[2],kitti_bbox[3]],image.shape[:2])
```

The function does some normalization which is essential for yolo and outputs following:

> (0.14763590391908976,
> 0.3397063758389261,
> 0.20452591656131477,
> 0.01810402684563757)

but when i try to check if the normalization is being done correctly with this code:

```
x = int(convert[0] * image.shape[0])
y = int(convert[1] * image.shape[1])
width = x+int(convert[2] * image.shape[0]) 
height = y+ int(convert[3] * image.shape[1])

cv.rectangle(image, (int(x), int(y)), (int(width), int(height)), (255,0,0), 2 )
```

the bounding box is misplaced:
[image]

Any suggestions ? Is conversion fucntion correct? or the problem is in the checking code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the centroid calculation wrong.

Kitti labels are given in the order of left, top, right, and bottom.

to get the centroid you have to do (left + right)/ 2 and (top + bottom)/2

so your code will become

```
x = (bbox[0] + bbox[2]) / 2.0

y = (bbox[1] + bbox[3]) / 2.0

w = bbox[2] - bbox[0]

h = bbox[3] - bbox[1]
```